# Why does my node.js application run fine on both my local environment and my Docker container but on the latter I can't load the site in the browser?

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, webpack, environment-variables

I recently updated my webpack dependency in a Vue/node.js application from 4.x to 5.x. After doing so the application continues to work without issues on my local system and in a Docker container (no errors in logs, etc.) but it won't load the app in a browser when using the Docker container?

In the process of upgrading from 4.x to 5.x I did have to make some changes.

Webpack 5.x deprecated `public` as an option for `devServer` so I changed my `vue.config.js` from:

```js
// ...
devServer: {
  port: 8081,
  public: process.env.PUBLIC_ADDRESS,
},
// ...
```

To:

```js
// ...
devServer: {
  port: 8081,
  host: process.env.PUBLIC_ADDRESS,
}
// ...
```

Then I had to update my `.env.development` file from:

`PUBLIC_ADDRESS=localhost:8081`

To:

`PUBLIC_ADDRESS=localhost`

Otherwise Webpack would complain.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The change from `public` to `host` seems to be the problem. Docker can't find its way out of the container when one uses `localhost`, changing the `PUBLIC_ADDRESS` property to `0.0.0.0` instead of `localhost` seems to have resolved the issue.

NOTE: The unfortunate side-effect of this is that when working locally node is going to bind to all the local machine's IPs instead of just localhost - which isn't ideal. Still looking for the solution to that one...

The following SO post put me on the right path: ttps://stackoverflow.com/questions/75525595/why-am-i-getting-error-getaddrinfo-enotfound-localhost8081-when-executing-n